# Intel HD 3000 - Shared Graphic Memory decreased from 4GB to 1.6GB upon installing drivers

Tags: windows-10, memory, drivers, graphics-card, intel-graphics

I have laptop with following specification:

**Model:** HP Probook 4530s

**Processor:** Intel Core-i3 2350M 2.30 GHz

**Graphic:** Intel HD 3000

**RAM:** 8gb

**OS:** Windows 10

**Before Driver Installation - 4GB Shared Memory:**

[image]

**Picture After Driver Installation:**

[image: After Driver Installation - 1.6GB Shared Memory]

I have the following Questions:

1. Why shared memory reduced to 1.6 GB and how to get it back to 4GB shared memory?
2. Why is it not showing any dedicated memory. Could this be an issue regarding the reduction of  shared memory?

Comment: What CPU do you have? And what problems are you experiencing?

Comment: You have gone through the Intel control panel options?

Comment: @Ramhound I have gone to Personalize -> System -> Display -> Display Adapter Properties. This is setting available in windows not specific to intel or anything

Comment: Have you listed all the modes for the adapter?

Comment: @Ramhound Here is the list to all modes I see after driver installation: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0By0ebicVSUGGX04wRG5mY1hjQTg

Comment: @JamieHanrahan I have Intel Core-i3 2350M 2.30Ghz . I am having the issue that my shared graphic memory should be around 4GB on my 8GB RAM but it shows only 1.6GB. It shows 4GB on default drivers as in picture but when I install intel HD 3000 drivers it wont show 4GB. you can see pictures link for reference

Comment: Yes, you said that originally. But is it _working?_ Does it pass e.g. dxdiag? Is there something that used to work on the machine that doesn't now?  That's what I'm asking about re. problems.

Comment: What's more puzzling is that there **are no** drivers for the HD3000 on Win10. The card was legacied by Intel. btw, the shared memory ought to be dynamic.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Yes, drivers are working fine and all ok. What actually is the case is that I just recently upgraded my ram from 4GB to 8GB. On 4GB RAM I had 1.6GB Shared Memory on intel HD 3000 which is perfectly OK. When I upgraded to 8GB RAM I was hoping that shared memory will increase from 1.6GB to around 4GB which is logical because more the RAM more the shared memory, but it didn't increased. I tried deleting intel HD 3000 driver and when I did. It started showing 4GB shared memory as in the first picture but then upon installing drivers again it shifted back to 1.6 GB of shared memory.

Comment: @Tetsujin How come ? I am using intel HD 3000 drivers on Windows 10 for quite long and able to play games like Rocket League. Yes intel gave up support for intel HD 3000 but its last driver update was around in 2016 and is working fine on Windows 10

Comment: Do you have a reason for thinking that the HD3000 can actually use more than 1.6 GB shared? If you have the correct driver for the card and it insists on 1.6 GB, that's probably the right number. Most people complain that too much of their RAM is lost to shared memory, not too little!

Comment: I see you got an answer from rgd1101 over at tomshardware who said that what you're seeing is normal; and it makes sense to me - I'd go with that. ( http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-3431974/intel-3000-shared-graphic-memory-decreased-4gb-6gb-installing-drivers.html )

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Yes you are right. I found an answer to both my question . 1- Intel HD 3000 doesn't support more than 1.6GB and before installing driver it was showing 4GB because Windows didn't know the exact capability of it. It was only showing logical number. 2- Integrated GPU's don't have dedicated memory.  I am trying to post my own answer but can't due to some network spamming issue. So you may post this as an answer.

Comment: @JamieHanrahan Yes , absolutely .

Comment: How come? No profit in it for them. Legacy chipset, no further sales, no point in going to the effort of writing drivers for a major platform update - last drivers were 2015 - see https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/81500/Intel-HD-Graphics-3000 btw, 1.6GB sounds about right for 32-bit support without going to the effort of full 64-bit addressing. Cheap & cheerful, low-end i3, that would have been their mindset.